# AWS cognito: "Access token does not contain openid scope"

Tags: oauth-2.0, amazon-cognito

I got this issue while trying to fetch user attributes from AWS Cognito.

[image]

I can't tell how it can be an "Invalid Token" because I have copied and pasted it, also I have make sure that it's the `accessToken` not `idToken` or anything else.

There are some other similar questions on this site but they don't address my issue:

["Access token does not contain openid scope" in AWS Cognito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52425678/access-token-does-not-contain-openid-scope-in-aws-cognito)

[Access token does not have the openid scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37354555/access-token-does-not-have-the-openid-scope)

**Update:** here my app client config

[image]

Comment: can you enter the token in jwt.io and show us which scopes it contains?

Comment: hi guys, Could you help to show the App Client Setting in Cognito and ensure openid was checked?

Comment: @PhanViệt You were right that I forgot to check the `openid` in the app client config, but I still got the same message after checking the option

Comment: @LêQuangBảo Please help check my answer and give any questions to me because I'm sure it works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, I got you detail.

**Short answer:** You must use **oauth2** Cognito authentication instead of using default Cognito authentication API in SDK.

Let me explain why you meet error: You're using Cognito authentication, then Cognito return to you an "access token" that not contains "openid" scope, you can paste the Token here to check: https://jwt.io/#encoded-jwt.

You have to use **oauth2** authentication to get the "access token" that contains "openid". In order to do it, you have to use Hosted UI or [AUTHORIZATION Endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/authorization-endpoint.html) to get the "access token".

You can try Hosted UI by access link (pls edit your domain + response_type + client_id + redirect_uri): https://tsunami.auth.us-east-2.amazoncognito.com/login?response_type=code&client_id=CLIENT_ID&redirect_uri=CALLBACK_SIGNIN_URL

You can use AUTHORIZATION Endpoint: https://tsunami.auth.us-east-2.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=CLIENT_ID&redirect_uri=CALLBACK_SIGNIN_URL&identity_provider=COGNITO and it will redirect to Hosted UI

Comment: I got a `redirect_mismatch` error using the Authorization Endpoint. Here my url: https://tsunami.auth.us-east-2.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=jb6hkb09vv90b48bbpe85p11t&redirect_uri=http://localhost:4200/pages/dashboard&identity_provider=COGNITO

Comment: @LêQuangBảo As your screenshots, the CLIENT ID should be "522j...", not "jb6hkb09vv90b48bbpe85p11t". So the rediect uri: "http://localhost:4200/pages/dashboard" doesn't match. Please help check your url built be matched with App Client Setting.

Comment: I am using custom UI instead of hosted UI and Auth api from aws amplify. Returned access token doesn't have openid scope. Is it fixable? or desired behaviour when we are not using hosted UI

Comment: It seems still to be not fixed: https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-android/issues/684

Answer (score 1):

Getting user info is an open id connect feature and requires the openid scope in the token.

I suspect the problem originates from not specifying this scope when you authenticated and got the token.

Usually you configure scopes such as these when authenticating:

- openid profile email

You also provide these in the OAuth Client trust entry configured in Cognito

- The profile scope enables you to get the user name from the user info endpoint
- The email scope enables you to get the email from the user info endpoint

See [step 9 of my write up](https://authguidance.com/2019/04/08/how-to-run-the-react-js-spa/) for an example

Comment: It depends also on the library you are using to get a token. From a previous post I seem to remember that some of the AWS specific libraries do not allow you to specify scopes when authenticating. If so I would ditch them and move to a standards based library.

Comment: I am getting the token by `amazon-cognito-identity-js`, how can I specify a scope in my authenticate request?

Comment: @LêQuangBảo Use Hosted UI or AUTHORIZATION Endpoint to OAuth2 and request scopes with Cognito User Pool as Provder.